# Get All dates for given month and year and join in same table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have data in below format in my table

[image]

How can I get date wise for every month and year  like below

[image]

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Are whtap and whcnc always 1 in the outcome?

Comment: other columns in table

Comment: There is nothing in your sample which show where you would get these values - please amend your sample to clarify.

Comment: I am simply lost on what "date wise for every month and year" means.  Your result data is just different from your sample data and it is not clear how you want it generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, personally, I would create a Calendar Table. You can quickly create a simple one with the below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalendarTable] ([CalendarDate] [date] NOT NULL,
                                    [CalenderYear] AS (DATEPART(YEAR, [CalendarDate])) PERSISTED,
                                    [CalenderMonth] AS (DATEPART(MONTH, [CalendarDate])) PERSISTED,
                                    [CalenderDay] AS (DATEPART(DAY, [CalendarDate])) PERSISTED,
                                    [CalenderMonthName] AS (DATENAME(MONTH, [CalendarDate])),
                                    [JulianDate] AS ((DATEPART(YEAR, [CalendarDate]) * (1000) + DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, [CalendarDate]), (1), (1)), [CalendarDate])) + (1)) PERSISTED);
GO
--Create a couple indexes
ALTER TABLE dbo.CalendarTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CalendarDate PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CalendarDate);
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_YearMonthDay ON dbo.CalendarTable (CalenderYear,CalenderMonth,CalenderDay);

GO
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101','21000101'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5)
INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarTable
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '19000101')
FROM Tally T;
```

Then is just a trivial case of joining your table to the calendar table:

```sql
SELECT YT.PlanYear,
       YT.PlanMonth,
       CT.CalendarDate,
       1 AS WHTAP,
       1 AS WHCNC
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON YT.PlanYear = CT.CalenderYear
                              AND YT.PlanMonth = CT.CalenderMonth;
```